# Java trace "Ljava.lang.String;@1ba22e94" while debugging return value of array

Tags: java, string

Has anyone encountered java string error, which is something like this "Ljava.lang.String;@1ba22e94" ? I encountered it while trying to debug the return value of array. What is it and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Give us code and an example run of the program (inputs/outputs) and we'll see what we can do. The question is too ambiguous without it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an error - the string representation of an array simply returns a (sort of) internal address. To see the actual content of the array you can use:

```
Arrays.toString(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the class representation of a String array. You could use

```
String arrayContents = Arrays.toString(myStringArray);
```

to display the contents. All these representations can be found in [Class.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

```
Element Type        Encoding
boolean             Z
byte                B
char                C
double              D
float               F
int                 I
long                J
short               S 
Class or Interface  LClassName;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error. It is the representation of the Object.